# Deploying an app on Google App Engine path to certificate not provided error

Tags: google-app-engine, boot2docker, gcloud

For the past few days I have been trying to trace the source of the error shown in the blockquote in trying to deploy an app to google app engine on a windows machine using the command:

```
> gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml
```

> Beginning deployment... Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and
>   ready.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):    ...
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.../lib\docker\docker\tls.py", line 46, in
>   **init**
>
> 'Path to a certificate and key files must be provided'
>
> TLSParameterError: Path to a certificate and key files must be
>   provided through the client_config param. TLS configurations should
>   map the Docker CLI client configurations.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue?

FYI: I have already set the environment variables `DOCKER_CERT_PATH`, `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` and `DOCKER_HOST` as set by Docker.

Comment: When you say "as set by Docker," are you using [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/)? Can you check the output of `ls $DOCKER_CERT_PATH`: do you see `ca.pem`,   `cert.pem`, and `key.pem`?  Have you tried connecting to the same Docker instance using the `docker` command? Consider using the `--docker-build=remote` option with `gcloud preview app deploy`; this will obviate the need for a local Docker installation, and all of the configuration that accompanies it.

Comment: @ZacharyNewman
Yes, I am using boot2docker. I have DOCKER_CERT_PATH and the path in my environment variable list, but the output of ls $DOCKER_CERT_PATH is "cannot access...". When I put in docker in the command it says, " Couldn't read ca cert 'C:\Users\rediet\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm'\ca.pem". I really don't know what's happening...

Comment: OK, it looks like there's some trouble with boot2docker, and not with the gcloud tool. Is there a reason hosted builds (`--docker-build=remote`) won't work for you? This will get rid of the need for boot2docker. Otherwise, I'd recommend filing a bug with the boot2docker folks.

Comment: This should qualify for an answer on this post, no?